# Where can I find the source code of the "halt" tool?

Tags: unix, open-source, bsd, halt

Can anyone link up the source of the **halt** tool? It is a binary usually located in */sbin* which shuts down the system. I did some search and I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu at least, `/sbin/halt` is a symlink to `/sbin/reboot`, which is a part of [upstart](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/upstart/maverick). Get it [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/upstart/maverick/annotate/head:/util/reboot.c).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of halt from busybox.  The linux/bsd/whatever one is probably similar in many ways, although a little more elaborate :)

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#EKZaOgYQHwo/unstable/sources/busybox-1.2.1.tar.gz%7C5l79Bld9wLE/busybox-1.2.1/init/halt.c&q=halt.c%20lang:c

This URL appears to have a copy of the sysvinit source:

ftp://ftp.cistron.nl/pub/people/miquels/sysvinit/sysvinit-2.86.tar.gz

The halt source should be in that archive.

Answer (score 0):

The code for NetBSD is here : http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sbin/reboot/reboot.c?rev=1.35.4.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try /sbin/, some tools like shutdown are located there. If you are looking to restart your computer give:

> shutdown -r now